# Quaternion Rotation errors

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, quaternions

Recently, I’m using the source to do rotation on my 3D models. However, a problem occurred when calling the function:
**RotationBetweenVectors**, defined in **Tutorial 17**(
link: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/).
I want to rotate vector _from to vector _to using Quaternion method.
Two vectors are defined as following and a quat between them is calculated.

```
vec3 _from(0, -0.150401f, 0.93125f),  _to(-0.383022f, -0.413672f, 1.24691f);
quat _rot = RotationBetweenVectors(_from, _to);

vec3 _to1 = _rot * _from;
vec3 _to2 = _rot * _from * inverse(_rot);
```

then I use this quat ***_rot*** to multiply vector ***_from***. Unluckly, the result ***_to1*** and ***_to2*** are neither equal to vector ***_to***.

```
_rot gives {x=0.0775952041 y=-0.140000001 z=-0.0226106234 w=0.986847401}
_to1 gives {x=-0.264032304 y=-0.285160601 z=0.859544873 }
_to2 gives {x=-0.500465572 y=-0.390112638 z=0.697992325 }
```

I appreciate it if any friend could help me out this problem?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here.

First, if you want a vector v1 to rotate and finish exactly at same position of vector v2, they must be of the same length.

In your case, `_to` has different length than `_from`. I suggest you to normalize them:

```
_to = normalize(_to);
_from = normalize(_from);
```

Second, as you have prompted, a rotation via quaternion is done by this operator:

```
v1 = quat * Pin * inverse(quat);
```

the problem is that Pin must be a quaternion too, not a vector (you have defined `_from` to be a vec3). Notice that, in your original operator, it could be rewritten as:

```
vec3 _to2 = (_rot * _from) * inverse(_rot);
```

where the inner parens results in a vec3 that is multiplied by `inverse(_rot)`.

So, to solve this, it means that your operator must be something like that (a quaternion multiplication):

```
quat Pin = {0, _from};
quat result = _rot * Pin * inverse(_rot);
```

Now, you only need to convert this quaternion to a vec3 again:

```
_to2 = axis(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you cannot multiply a `vec3` to a `quat`, as you do below:

```
vec3 _to1 = _rot * _from;
```

You will have to convert `_from` from `vec3` to a `vec4` by adding a `1` in the forth place i.e.

```
vec4 _from2 = vec4(_from, 1);
```

Also, convert `_rot` from a `quat` to a 4x4 matrix, say `_rot2`. The tutorial you refer to, mentions that it can be done using:

```
mat4 RotationMatrix = quaternion::toMat4(quaternion);
```

Then you should be able to multiply `_from2` to `_rot2` to get the `_to` vector.